# Reg exp in java for alphabets,numbers and comma

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression in java which should allow alphabets,number and comma. Could anyone please help?
I am using the code. But it is not working

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9,]$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(object.toString());
boolean bcheck = m.find();
```

Comment: You may use `boolean bcheck = object.toString().matches("[A-Za-z0-9,]+")`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this expression is allowing all special characters also. I need an expression which strictly allow only alphabets,numbers and comma.For example it should allow all the below patterns :

Comment: You are wrong. You did not even try my solution. `.matches` requires a full string match. Do not use `.find()`.